# OpenLayers2 - setting opacity to a webservice layer (if statement)

Tags: openlayers-2

I've got an openlayers application which calls the layers from MSSQL via a web service.
The problem is that I want to set an opacity level for one of the layers (If layer name = X, set opacity level to Y).

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking ofr the Layer's [Opacity](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.opacity) property.

You should have a look at this sample: [Layer Opacity Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/layer-opacity.html)

I can generally change the opacity by using the [SetOpacity](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.setOpacity) function, like this:

`map.layers[4].setOpacity(0.2);`